# Filter out command completions with specific prefixes

Tags: completion, completing-read, filtering, vertico

I am using command completions, and would like to 'filter' out certain built-in packages. For example, typing "text";

[image: Example completions]

In these completions, I would like to filter out/hide the entries that start with `html2text`, `mail-`, `bibtex-` and `eww-`, as those are built-in packages I do not use.

How can I best do this? I am using Emacs 29.1, `vertico` and `orderless` with their default/most basic configurations;

```
    (use-package orderless
  :defer 1
  :config
  (orderless-define-completion-style orderless+initialism
    (orderless-matching-styles
      '(orderless-initialism orderless-literal orderless-regexp)))
  (setq
    completion-styles '(orderless basic)
    completion-category-defaults nil
    completion-category-overrides '(
      (file (styles partial-completion))
      (command (styles orderless+initialism))
      (symbol (styles orderless+initialism))
      (variable (styles orderless+initialism)))
    read-file-name-completion-ignore-case t
    read-buffer-completion-ignore-case t
    completion-ignore-case t))
```

Answer (score 0):

(I assume you mean filter *interactively*, and not just call `completing-read' applying a filter in the call.)

I can't answer for Vertico or Orderless, I'm afraid.

---

But with [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) what you want is trivial to do.

**`M-x text S-SPC ^\(html2\|mail\|bibtex\|eww\) S-TAB C-~`**

Breaking that down:

1. **`M-x text S-SPC`**: [Apropos](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Apropos_Completions)-match `text`, which amounts to matching `text` as a substring.
2. **`^\(html2\|mail\|bibtex\|eww\) S-TAB`**: Apropos-match that regexp, which matches those alternatives at the start of each completion candidate. That is, restrict the matches to candidates (all of which have substring `text`) that have those prefixes.
3. **`C-~`**: Take the *complement* of those candidates, within the previous set of candidates. That is, remove, from the set of candidates matching `text`, all those that match the prefixes `html2`, `mail`, `bibtex`, and `eww`.

Such progressive filtering, applying different filters one-by-one, like interactive shell piping, I call ["progressive completion"](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Nutshell_View#ProgressiveCompletion).

Removing a set of matches I call ["chipping away the non-elephant"](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Nutshell_View#ChippingAway).

These are the most commonly used operations in Icicles.

Answer (score 0):

With vertico and orderless you're almost there, all you need is to add a style dispatcher to your configuration, also mentioned in the orderless README.

Now you can prefix a term with `!` to exclude matching candidates.

```lisp
(defun without-if-bang (pattern _index _total)
    (cond
     ((equal "!" pattern)
      '(orderless-literal . ""))
     ((string-prefix-p "!" pattern)
      `(orderless-without-literal . ,(substring pattern 1)))))

(setq orderless-style-dispatchers '(without-if-bang))
```

Comment: Hi Bram, thanks for the orderless example. This works as expected; it filters out any keyword typed into the buffer that is prefixed with `!`. However I am hoping to have a pre-existing list of keywords that I could 'hard-code', so that don't have to explicitly `!exclude` them. How would you go ahead with that? I figure I could assign a style-dispatcher to a unique character that inserts the `without-literal` style, but that still requires explicit action in the search pattern...